# %2520 (Double space) in URL for URL with spaces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, double, url-rewriting, space

My URL structure is like

```
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=dir1
```

To be able to access it from

```
http://www.example.com/folder/dir1
```

and at the same time redirect the 1st URL to 2nd one, my htaccess (in 'folder') is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The trouble is that if any directory name in URL contains a 'space', the URL shows %2520 instead of the 'space'.
Please advice in modifying the htaccess so it shows %20 or preferrably a simple 'space'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding a `NE` on the redirect ie

```
 RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]
```

**EDIT**

> Since you've read my htaccess, do you see any possiblity of shortening it further

Below are a couple of comments

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301]

#this looks redundant with last rule, and could be deleted?
RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]

#this says if not an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#and this says if it IS an existing directory
#Is this what you wanted, or should it be not an existing directory i.e 
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d instead
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.. Since you've read my htaccess, do you see any possiblity of shortening it further?